# Как сделать по REST whois.apnic.net? Есть ли официальные сервисы объединяющие все 5 региональных регистраторов?

Tags: php, whois

У меня пока получилось найти на stackoverflow ответ для RIPE
И он вот https://rest.db.ripe.net/search.txt?query-string=193.0.6.1

Для Apnic догадался в F12 посмотреть, но там ответ JSON:
https://wq.apnic.net/query?searchtext=193.0.6.1 (есть ли версия .txt или версии официальные?)

Comment: Чем JSON не подходит? с ним ведь работать проще чем с простым текстом...